# Disease Probability

Tags: probability

300 people tested for a disease (100% accuracy test).
10% chance each person has a disease, independently of whether any other person in group has disease.
Up to six blood samples can be combined (k =1,2,3,4,5 or 6).
Negative = no k people in the subgroup will have the disease and no further test is necessary
Positive = at least one of the k people in the subgroup has the disease then each one is tested individually
For what value of k will expected value of test performed be smallest, and what is that expected # of tests?

My Answer:
Let T be the number test needed fpr a group of k people
Let X be the number of positive for a group of k people

Expected smallest
E(T) = 1*P(X=0)+60*(P>=1)
Since X~Binomial(1,0.08),
P(X=0)=.0736
 and P(X=>1)=.0736
E(T) = 4.4896

Expected Value
E(T) = 1*P(X=0)+60*(P>=1)
Since X~Binomial(6,0.08),
P(X=0)=1.5895x10^-7
 and P(X=>1)=.00001
E(T) = some weird number

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your calculations at all. Where does $0.08$ come from?

If test are grouped into groups of $k$ tests (where $k\gt1$ and divides $300$) then I would have thought that there would be $\frac{300}{k}$ groups and the expected number of tests on each group would be $1+k( 1-0.9^k)$ and so the overall expected number of tests would be is $$\frac{300}{k} +300 - 300\times 0.9^k$$

You could use calculus to find a minimum, but since $k$ is an integer, it may just be faster to test integer values.

Note that the decision rule *"Positive = at least one of the k people in the subgroup has the disease then each one is tested individually"* is in fact inefficient: in some cases you can avoid testing the last member of a group, reducing the number of tests needed.